# white space to the right of my html/css webpage

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I am having a hard time understanding why there is a small white space next to my webpage. I have checked inspect element and it says the body stops before the white space begins (as in the border of my body is where is want it to be). I am a beginner at writing HTML and CSS so hopefully this will be an easy problem to fix!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


<!--Logo + Social media and login + navbar + search bar-->
    <div class="login">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li class="loginbutton"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="pull-left">
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="twitter" src="#"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img class="facebook" src="#"></a></li>
                    <li class="pressreleases"><a href="#">Press</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>      

    <div class="logo">
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="#" border="0"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Popular</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Database</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="searchbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form>
                    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Lookup symbol..." required>
                    <input name="Submit" class="button" type="submit" value="Search">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <!-- end Logo + Social media and login + navbar + search bar-->

    <div class="frontpage">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="headliner">
                        <h3>New releases</h3>
                        <p>Learn everything you need to know. <p>
                        <p><a href="#">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="ad1">
                        <h1>Ad</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>  


    <footer>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="top">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="middle1">
                <li><a href="#">Advertise</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="middle2">
                <li><a href="#">Application for Internship/Position</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="bottom">
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of use</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p>2014<p>
        </div>
    </footer>


    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
            /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            Logo + navbar
            + login/social media + search bar   v
            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/

            .logo {
                max-width: 280px;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
            }
            .logo img {
                width: 150%;
            }
            .logo .container-fluid {
                height:135px;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                width: 100%;
                padding-top:5px;
            }

            .nav .navbar {
                background-color: #40517f;
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 5;
                padding: 5;
                overflow: hidden;
                position:relative; bottom:50px;
            }
            .nav .navbar li {
                float: left;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-color: #40517f;
            }
            .nav .navbar li a{
                display: block;
                width: 300px;
                font-weight: none;
                color: #40517f;
                background-color: #B4C8E8;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }
            .nav .navbar li a:hover {
                color: #666666;
                background-color: #CAD8EF;
                FONT-WEIGHT:none;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }

            .login .container-fluid {
                background-color: #ffffff;
                padding-top:5px;
                z-index: 1;
                height: 30px;
            }
            .login .pull-right li {
                float: right; 
                list-style: none;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .login .pull-right li a {
                display: inline;
                padding: 10px;
                color: #40517f;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }
            .login .pull-right li a:hover {
                color: #B4C8E8;
                margin-top: 0px;
                margin-bottom: 0px;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }
            .login .pull-left li {
                float: left;
                list-style: none;
                color: #666666;
                font-size: 14px;
                position: relative;
                right: 50px;
                overflow: hidden;

            }
            .login .pull-left li a {
                display: inline;
                padding: 10px;
                opacity: .8;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }
            .login .pull-left .facebook {
                width: auto;
                height: 20px;
                vertical-align: sub;
            }
            .login .pull-left .twitter {
                width: 20px;
                height: auto;
                vertical-align: sub;
            }
            .login .pull-left .pressreleases {
                right: 3 px;
                vertical-align: sub;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }
            .searchbar {
                background-color:#D1D1D1;
                text-align:center;
                position:relative;bottom:75px;
                border-style: solid;
                border-width: 2px;
                border-color: #40517f;
            }
            .search {
                width: 250px;
                padding:8px 15px;
                background-color:#FFFFFF;
                border:3px solid #D1D1D1;
                color: #666666;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }
            .button {
                position:relative;
                padding:6px 15px;
                left:-2px;
                background-color:#40517f;
                color:#ffffff;
                opacity: .6;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }
            .button:hover  {
                background-color:#B4C8E8;
                border-color: #B4C8E8;
                color:#ffffff;
                opacity: 1;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
            }

            /* !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            Logo + navbar +       ^
            login/social media + search bar 
            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/


            /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            Frontpage   v
            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/

            .frontpage {
                position:relative; bottom:50px;
            }
            /*
            Height and width for all of "frontpage" are just placeholders! 
            Make sure to get right of them when content is added.
            */
            .frontpage .container-fluid .headliner {
                background-color: #efefef;
                height: 400px;
            }

            .frontpage .container-fluid .ad1 {
                background-color: #efefef;
                height: 400px;
            }

            /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            Frontpage   ^
            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/


            /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            Footer   v
            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/



            footer {
                background-color: #666666;  
                text-align:center;
            }

            footer .top {
                list-style: none;
                color: #478bca;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
                font-size: 18px;
                padding-top:15px;
            }

            footer .top li {
                display: inline;

            }

            footer .top li:before {
                content: " | ";
            }

            footer .top li:first-child:before {
                content: none;
            }

            footer .middle1 {
                list-style: none;
                color: #478bca;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
            footer .middle1 li {
                display: inline;
            }
            footer .middle1 li:before {
                content: " | ";
            }
            footer .middle1 li:first-child:before {
                content: none;
            }

            footer .middle2 {
                list-style: none;
                color: #478bca;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            footer .middle2 li {
                display: inline;
            }
            footer .middle2 li:before {
                content: " | ";
            }
            footer .middle2 li:first-child:before {
                content: none;
            }
            footer .bottom {
                list-style: none;
                color: #478bca;
                font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
                font-size: 18px;
            }

            footer .bottom li {
                display: inline;
            }
            footer .bottom li:before {
                content: " | ";
            }
            footer .bottom li:first-child:before {
                content: none;
            }



            footer .copyright {
                background-color: #666666;
                height: 60px;
            }

            footer .copyright p {
                color: #D1D1D1;
                padding-top: 10px;
                font-size: 12px;
            }

            /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            Footer  ^
            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
```

Comment: It would be helpful to create a jsfiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I went ahead and put this code up on my site. its www.ipostats.com

Comment: Try to use a css reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: This didn't fix my problem

Comment: Usually when I have this problem it relates to one of my values where I used a percentage. Try changing some of them and seeing if it helps, I'll give the code another once over and see if I can see anything.

Comment: thanks for your help. I just went through and changed all of my width percentages and didn't have any luck. White space is still there.

Comment: I find it strange how inspect element doesn't include the whitespace as part of the body. Any input on that? If you want to take a look for yourself, the website is http://www.ipostats.com

Comment: actually the whitespace is even outside the html according to inspect element. I've checked on different browsers and it is still there, also when I change screen size it is still there.

Comment: It's not there if you take just the code you posted above so that tells me it has something to do with an image.

Comment: ok I'll go play around with all of my images and get back to you

Comment: I changed all of my images and didn't seem to have any luck.

Comment: However, I did delete my footer section of html and then it went away, which leads me to believe there's something in the html that is making it do that. I also deleted all of the css to see if it would still scroll and it did so I don't think its in the css. Nonetheless something with the footer though for sure.

Comment: I just figured it out; the <div class="row">'s in my footer needed to have a <div class="container"> around them. Thanks for all of your help

Comment: Glad you figured it out, sorry I wasn't more help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code at top of css:

```
html, body {        
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

see the result:
http://jsfiddle.net/zpq3uxuq/

Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 1):

The div class="row"s in the footer need to have a div class="container" around them.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you are referring to the white space between the `div.frontpage` and `footer`, then check my answer below:</strike>

```
.frontpage {
position: relative;
bottom: 50px;
}
```

Remove the `bottom:50px` to resolve the issue.
[`bottom` explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom)

### UPDATE

In light of the comment from the OP, I've updated my answer:

The issue is related to the negative margin set by the following `CSS` declaration:

```
.row {
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Remove the negative margin to resolve the issue.

Comment: that is not the white space I'm referring to. If you scroll right on the page you'll see a white column running parallel to the page. I don't want that there.